# getting error "requireNativeComponent: 'RNSVGLinearGradient' was not found in the UIManager..." while rendering Pie Chart using react-native-chart-kit

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-svg, react-native-chart-kit

I have used `react-native-chart-kit` and `react-native-svg` in my project, initially I created my project in Expo, where it was working fine(the Pie Chart was rendering perfect with no issues) but when I ejected Expo, and ran project with `react-native run-android`, I received this error.

I have tried to upgrade/downgrade the versions of `react-native-chart-kit` and `react-native-svg`, but still the error is same. Also linked `react-native-svg` with react-native(still no luck)

And what I don't understand that when I work on Expo, I got no error(not even after building Release APK), but when I eject expo and run with `react-native run-android`, it produces error.

Also, I have created a clean project with only one screen where I rendered Pie Chart, but the error was same.

Please provide something to go on, Stuck badly.